# Regarding partition and Installation

Tags: partitioning

I am currently using Windows XP on my Compaq Pressario V3000 laptop. I would like to remove Windows and install/use UBUNTU. Do I have to format all the partitions (NTFS) or the one on which windows is installed. Kindly help.

Comment: Please supply more information of the partitions for more detailed and specific support.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one NTFS partition then use the Use Whole Disc option on the ubuntu installer.

Your question suggests you have more than one NTFS partition. If this is the case - perhaps data - then formatting all partitions will lose that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu in two ways:

1. You can install it from inside of Windows:-
   run wubi.exe in the Ubuntu iso after extracting it will ask you for a partition show an empty partition it will install as single file there you can use both Windows and Ubuntu
2. You can boot from cd/pen drive and choose the correct partition you only need one empyt partition which you have to format as ext2/3/4 of fat so nothin will happen to your Windows

but if you want to remove Windows just remove windows partition and reformat it as ext2/3/4 and install Ubuntu there.